# getting yahoo contacts in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, yahoo-api

I'm developing an app using phonegap. I want to get contacts from yahoo after logging in, and I  got stuck at this. I want to know that, whether it can be done with JavaScript. But don't know where to start.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: phonegap won't help access the Yahoo APIs.

Comment: So is it not possible to get contacts after logging into the app using yahoo

Comment: That's not what I said.  You can use the yahoo API, but that has nothing to do with phonegap or Cordova.  You should do a bit more research and pick tags that will attract people who work with the technology you are asking for help with.

Answer (score 0):

As of this date (2015-08-11), there are NO plugins to support the Yahoo API for contacts. This is a link to search for such plugins http://plugins.cordova.io/npm/index.html?q=yahoo